# Load frame on select

Tags: javascript, html

The following HTML code is working as expected. What I need is a drop down option where the user will select any platform and the righ frame will load the required file.

```
<a href="android.html" target="dynamic"> android form </a>
<a href="J2ME.html" target="dynamic"> J2ME form </a>
<a href="windows.html" target="dynamic"> windows form </a>
```

The following html generates the drop down option but how to make the required pages load automatically?

```
<form>
Platform:
<select name='platform'>
<option>Android  </option>
<option> J2ME </option>
<option> Windows </option>

</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            <html>
            <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadFrame()
            {
            var s=document.getElementById("platform").value;

            document.getElementById("loadContainer").innerHTML=""
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
            iframe.src = s;
            document.getElementById("loadContainer").appendChild(iframe);
            }
            </script>
            </head>
            <body>

            <div style="float:left">
            <form>
                Platform:
                <select id='platform' onchange="loadFrame()">
                    <option value="android.html">Android</option>
                    <option value="J2ME.html">J2ME</option>
                    <option value="Windows.html">Windows</option>
                </select>
            </form>
            </div>

            <div id="loadContainer" style="float:right"></div>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try such a variant:

First, set values for your options like this and set the `onchange` event for select element:

```
<form>
Platform:
<select name='platform' onchange='loadFrame(this)' id='OSList'>
    <option value="1.html">Android</option>
    <option value="2.html">J2ME</option>
    <option value="3.html">Windows</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="loadContainer"></div>
```

Second, create a function, that creates an iFrame with the `src` got from selected option value and appends it somewhere (like to div#loadContainer):

```
function loadFrame(comboBox)
{
    var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
    frame.src = comboBox.options[comboBox.selectedIndex].value;
    var container = document.getElementById("loadContainer");
    container.innerHTML = "";
    container.appendChild(frame);
}
```

​Look at the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HXwDT/)

If you are able to use jQuery (or other frameworks you may bind to the select `onchange` event in such a way via JS):

```
var el = $("#OSList");
el.change(function() {
    var frame = document.createElement("iframe");
    frame.src = el.val();
    $("#loadContainer").empty().append(frame)
});
```

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HXwDT/2/)
​

Comment: I would recommend using a better binding scheme than that defined in the HTML, via something like jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
            <html>
            <head>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            function loadFrame()
            {
            var select_value=document.getElementById("platform").value;

            window.location =select_value;
            }
            </script>
            </head>
            <body>

            <form>
                Platform:
                <select id='platform' onchange="loadFrame()">
                    <option value="andriod.html">Android</option>
                    <option value="j2me.html">J2ME</option>
                    <option value="windows.html">Windows</option>
                </select>
            </form>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add an empty frame in your page and directly change its src, there's no need to retrieve html content, like below:

```
<html>
        <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function loadFrame(comboBox)
         {
        var frame = window.frames['platformFrame'],
            src = comboBox.options[comboBox.selectedIndex].value;
            frame.window.location.href = src; //use window.location to avoid browser capability.
        }
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>

        <form>
            Platform:
            <select id='platform' onchange="loadFrame()">
                <option value="andriod.html">Android</option>
                <option value="j2me.html">J2ME</option>
                <option value="windows.html">Windows</option>
            </select>
        </form>
        <iframe src="" id="platformFrame"></iframe>
        </body>
        </html>
```